# Advanced Search with Confluence CQL Error

Tags: api, cql, confluence, confluence-rest-api

Iam looking for a order function in confluence CQL.

I want to order by TYPE (page, comment, etc)
How is it possible?

I tried this, but it doenst work:
https://myconfluence.site/rest/api/content/search?cql=text~%22apos%22&type=page&expand=body.storage&filter=order+by+asc

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you mixed things up a bit :)

This query works for me and orders by **id**

```
/rest/api/content/search?cql=type=page+and+text~"apos"+order+by+id+asc&expand=body.storage
```

Lets see the problems one by one:

- *filter=order+by+asc* This does not work, as it is part of the cql syntax
- *order+by+asc* You have to tell which field should be ordered by (e.g. id or type)
- *text~%22apos%22&type=page* Do not separate with "&", as it is interpreted as 2 query params and not as single cql command. You have to write the key-word "and" to combine several terms.

I hope this solves your issue. Ordering by type would not have any affect in your example as you only search for pages.

Find further information here:

- [Advanced searching using CQL](https://developer.atlassian.com/confdev/confluence-rest-api/advanced-searching-using-cql)
- [Performing text searches using CQL](https://developer.atlassian.com/confdev/confluence-rest-api/advanced-searching-using-cql/performing-text-searches-using-cql)